Как реализовать цикл for на нужное число раз в шаблоне Django
Как реализовать в Django template без костылей:
{% for i in range(n) %}
   <код>
{% endfor %}

Неожиданная проблемка. Временно повторяю <код> два раза, но это жесткий костыль. Везде в примерах фор используется только с итерируемыми объектами, поочередно перебираемыми. С моей стороны нелепо пихать рэндж в контекст. Должно быть что-то элементарное, что - не могу найти. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Элементарное - {% for i in '12' %} хотя это тоже костыль https://stackoverflow.com/q/48637178

Уже неплохо. Спасибо
